# Multiple Events configuration under TopicConfigurations in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have refereed the following to configure the multiple events but I am unable to do so.
I need to configure the two events like  "**s3:ObjectCreated:Put | s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload**" but getting the error message like event object is not found. Can Anyone help me on the same to configure the multiple events trigger?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_TopicConfiguration.html

```
        - NeedsTopicConfiguration
        -
          TopicConfigurations:
            - Events: "s3:ObjectCreated:Put | s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload"
              Topic: "Testing"
              Filter:
                S3Key:
                  Rules:
                    - Name: suffix
                      Value: ".png"
```

**Error Message :**

`The event is not supported for notifications (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID:`

Comment: Can you include the actual error message?

Comment: Included the error message as well.

Comment: Note you should typically use `s3:ObjectCreated:*` if you simply want to request notification regardless of the API that was used to create an object. That covers all the bases (Put, Post, Copy, and CompleteMultipartUpload).

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation specifies that Events can be an array of strings, so you'll need something like this

```
     AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
     Resources:
       S3Bucket
         Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
         Properties:
           AccessControl: Private
           NotificationConfiguration:
             TopicConfigurations:
               - Topic: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:TestTopic'
                 Event: 's3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject'
               - Topic: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:TestTopic'
                 Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload'
     Outputs:
       BucketName:
         Value: !Ref S3Bucket
         Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket with a notification configuration.
```

Comment: Even I have tired the way you have mentioned. But, unfortunately getting the same error message "Encountered Unsupported format Events". I have tried with Event as well but getting the below error message "Event accepted only String value."

Comment: @VasantharajDava are you using CloudFormation?

Comment: Yes @Michael Anckaert

Comment: @VasantharajDava Updated my answer to show CloudFormation usage

Comment: I may need to use the common filter logic for both the event. Can you help me on that as well?